# Frequent Popup asking to sign in to iTunes Store in Production mode

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins, itunes-store

**Issue:**
Getting frequent popups asking to sign in to iTunes Store in both development and Production mode(Live version of app on App store). Popup occurs each time on app starts and asks for password frequent times, the below code is called each time on app start to check the subscription status and on particular subscription page.

Plugin Used : https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

**Code / steps to reproduce**

On calling window.inAppPurchase.getReceipt() returns receipt in base64 string  then to validate the receipt i call getlatestReceiptData()  on node server, calling 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt' for sandbox mode and 'buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt' for production mode, then compare purchases  to get the active purchase.

```
window.inAppPurchase.getReceipt().then(function (receipt) {
    getlatestReceiptData(receipt).then(function(latest_purchase){
            var timeStamp = Date.now();
               if (purchase && purchase.expires_date_ms && purchase.expires_date_ms > timeStamp) {
                            purchased = true;
                } else{ 
                           purchased = false;
               }
     });           
}).catch(function (error) {
    Utils.log(JSON.stringify(error), 'error');
    deferred.reject(error);
 });
```

Console output

**Type of product** - subscription

**System Information:**

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.12 
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v7.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`? That would always trigger credential checks.

Refreshing the receipt asks the App Store for the latest copy of the receipt. Refreshing a receipt does not create any new transactions. Although you should avoid refreshing multiple times in a row, this action would have same result as refreshing it just once.

Restoring purchases prompts for the user’s App Store credentials, which interrupts the flow of your app: because of this, don’t automatically restore purchases, especially not every time your app is launched.

```
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html
```